# python doesn't run script with 'python <script name>'

Tags: python

I'm gett a strange problem when running python script from linux, it doesn't seem to bother running the script file (I've put a print statement on the first line and it doesn't come out):

```
zl@o-xterm-71 h2bin> python main.py
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb  4 2013, 18:00:47)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

The script runs fine on my laptop with 2.7.5, and even with 2.4.3 so I'd assume it's not a version problem. Should be something simple that I missed.. Anyone had this before? Thanks!

edit1：
dummy.py:

```
def main():
    print "it works"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output:

```
zl@o-xterm-71 h2bin> python dummy.py
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb  4 2013, 18:00:47)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Typing 'python' gives the exact same thing.

Comment: What is the script doing? You may have some errors in it. Post the source.

Comment: Was this file saved in Windows? Notepad usually adds a `txt` extension...

Comment: @arturhoo: The executable would complain about a non-existent file.

Comment: please see edit, and no, I was editting on mac, and copied to linux

Comment: What do you see after running `which python`?

Comment: @alecxe /home/zl/src/tools/linux/python/273/bin/python which is mapped from a software repo

Comment: I bet there is smth wrong with this mapped python. Could you check `python dummy.py` using system-wide python?

Comment: If you add the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python`, `chmod +x` the script and then run it like a normal executable, what happens?

Comment: I'm out of my element here, but I feel compelled to point out that it seems odd that the prompt is '>' instead of a more familiar '$'. Would this have anything to do with it?

Comment: @alecxe the default one runs okay but it's python 2.4.3 which fails the version test of the original script..

Comment: @sapi nothing changes :/

Comment: @verbsintransit haha nope I changed PS1

Comment: okay, it's already something interesting. What do see while running `python --help`?

Answer (score 1):

```
tarvalon:/tmp$ cat dummy.py 
def main():
    print("it works")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
tarvalon:/tmp$ python dummy.py 
it works
```

So, it works. There's some problem with your installation. Looks like your python file is a script that is calling the real python binary without parameters. Best commands to debug that: file `which python`, cat `which python` and, most important, python --help.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about this, but I think the quotes are messing things up for you.

Change:

```
print “it works”
```

To

```
print "it works"
```

Comment: sorry.. the input method was messing the edit, I have the ASCII quotes in my script

Comment: Python would produce a syntax error on this input, not silently ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You could explain this behaviour if someone/something put a wrapper script/program named `python` in your PATH, that runs a real Python interpreter, but neglects to pass the arguments.